# Unexpected memory usage on Linux

Tags: linux

I have a problem regarding disk space usage on Linux.
I'm working on a Linux machine via remote login.
I have been allowed to use **10GB** of space on Linux machine by system administrator. Currently I'm using only **579MB** in my home directory, this I checked via `du -h` command.

But when I put more data, the permission is denied, I investigated using `quota -s` and it shows that I'm using **8.7GB** memory!!

I don't know where extra files are located excluding my home directory so I can delete them.

Comment: Check with this command what is real usage of your home dir: cd ~; du -sh ../$USER

Comment: @Romeo I have checked it earlier its **579MB** but the problem is I couldn't find where else I'm using space ...

Comment: Please check it on exact way I offer you. And is it quota for this filesystem only?

Comment: yes I have checked it as it is. But not sure about quota filesystem.

Comment: Please contact your sysadmin. And just for the record check if you have any files in /tmp and /var/tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access to the server, you can check disk usage by using `df -h` - this will check the space available on the disk partitions instead of just within your home directory.

If you don't have root access to the server, your next point of contact should be the owner of the server, as Romeo pointed out.

Also, your disk usage may be used in "dotfolders", the `du` command only checks regular folders by default. As per [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356902/why-doesnt-this-show-the-hidden-files-folders), you can check disk space in all folders with this command:

```
du -sch .[!.]* * | sort -h
```